# Kinematics - angle of projection given relation between speed at highest point and half of that

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

For a projectile launched from a point on horizontal ground, the speed when it is at the greatest height is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}$ times the speed when it is at half of its greatest height. Determine the angle of projection.

I attempted to define the velocity vectors, after which i multiply it by $\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}$, which simply gives me $45^\circ$ as the angle of projection when i split the components, however it actually is $60^\circ$.

Kindly tell me how to find the answer to this, because i am getting $45^\circ$ after several attempts...

Comment: **Remember:** the $x$ and $y$ parts of the problem are decoupled; they do not affect one another..

Comment: I understand that, i made two equations from h - u^2sin^2 theta/2g...
i get a quadratic in sin theta, which i then go on to simplify and get 45 degrees... Could you hint me some variables to focus on? :/

Comment: Work the problem in terms of the components of velocity. You can do it by pure constant-acceleration kinematics or by energy concerns.

Comment: The time required to reach the greatest height would be equal to half of the total time, so can i assume that half of the highest point would take a fourth of the total time?

Comment: *"can i assume that half of the highest point would take a fourth of the total time?"* Can you? Also notice that the problem does not mention time in the givens nor in the required answer, which means that you don't *need* to use time unless it makes your life easier.

Comment: Are you implying i should use the formula v^2 = u^2 + 2aS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14720/discussion-between-mathbreaker-and-dmckee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with x and y components of velocity and displacement separately. It is clear that at its greatest height the velocity in the y direction will be zero. So we have.

$$v_{y} = u_{y} - gt =  0 $$

Where $$u_{y} = u sin \theta $$

With $u$ being initial velocity and $v$ being the velocity at time t.

This allows you to solve for the time at which the projectile reaches its greatest height, then sub into.

$$ y = u_{y} t - \frac{1}{2} a t^{2} $$

This will give you $y_{max}$...... then equating speeds, where ${v_{\frac{h}{2},y}}$ is the speed in the y direction when the particle is at $\frac{1}{2}$ its max height we get:

$$
v_{x}^{2} = \frac{2}{5} \left(v_{x}^{2} + {v_{\frac{h}{2},y}}^{2} \right) $$

Since $v_{x}$ remains constant throughout(no force in x direction, gravity acts downwards).

This process should yield the answer..

I hope this is enough for you to go on.